# holomorphic image of Jordan curve.

Tags: complex-analysis

In general, holomorphic image of Jordan curve may not be a Jordan curve. (see the obvious case of costant function). Is there any sufficient condition regarding that holomorphic function which guarantees

1. image of Jordan curve under that function again a Jordan curve
2. Winding number of that Jordan curve is preserved

?

Answer (score 2):

Really nice functions will break the winding number. Like, polynomial nice.

Let's just assume that your original Jordan curve winds around $0$. Then the function $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ by $z\mapsto z^n$ will increase the winding number by a factor of $n$. Call your curve $\Gamma$. Then
$$
\int_\Gamma \frac{1}{z}\,dz = k
$$
for some $k$. Then
$$
\int_{f(\Gamma)} \frac{1}{z}\,dz = \int_{\Gamma} \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}\,dz=\int_{\Gamma} n\frac{z^{n-1}}{z^n}\,dz =nk 
$$

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is a holomorphic function, then the most basic condition that will ensure that $f$ preserves Jordan curves and winding numbers is that $f$ be a *homeomorphism*; i.e., a continuous function with a continuous (two-sided) inverse.  Since holomorphic functions are automatically continuous, you only need to check that it has a continuous inverse.  Can you see why this will preserve Jordan curves and winding numbers?

More generally, any *homotopy equivalence* will preserve winding numbers (though you have to take care to define this in the right way - ask if you want the full details), though I think it will take a bit more work to get a similar condition for Jordan curves.